# Remote Performance Monitor - Browser Based

Tags: node.js, performance, embedded, embedded-linux, node-red

I work with an ARM based embedded system with a Linux kernel and a fairly large filesystem image(~1GB). The kernel and filesystem are under my control, so I can add modules and re-build if necessary.

The system has Node.js and on top of this [Node-Red](http://nodered.org/) for an IOT application. I want to leverage the simple server capability of Node-Red to serve a web page showing graphically the system performance statistics.

I am considering building [collectd](https://collectd.org/index.shtml) for the target system and using it to write performance data to the filesystem. Then, I will use Node-Red/Node.js to present this information as a web page. This approach seems straightforward enough to be doable.

My question is: is there an alternative, established way of implementing such a remote system performance viewer? Or can anyone suggest a lightweight performance monitor and a method of displaying the statistics graphically on a web page?

Answer (score 0):

I started [node-spm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-spm) for that logging to Sematext Logsene and writing custom metrics to SPM. I collected also process and OS metrics. It's in an early stage and I will do in the next few weeks more on that.